# Need help connecting my Visualforce Page with Standard object detail page

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller

I have created One VFPage and controller. VFPage is to create new opportunity. After they create opportunity I want user to come back to this same page if they edit the opportunity, I have tried looking for the solution but I can't find anywhere. Please someone help me with this.

Below is the code for my VFPage

```
<apex:page controller=""="OpportunityInformationPage" >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Opportunity Edit" subtitle="New Opportunity"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Saveto}"/>
            <!--    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/> -->
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Opportunity Information">
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.Ownerid}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.Amount}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.IsPrivate}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.CloseDate}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.name}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.NextStep}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.Accountid}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.StageName}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.Type}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.Probability}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.LeadSource}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.Campaignid}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Additional Information">

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.OrderNumber__c}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.MainCompetitors__c}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.CurrentGenerators__c}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.DeliveryInstallationStatus__c}"/>

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.TrackingNumber__c}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Description Information">

                <apex:inputField value="{!oppstring.Description}"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

And Here is my controller?

```
public class OpportunityInformationPage {

    public opportunity oppstring{get; set;}

    public OpportunityInformationPage() {

        oppstring= new opportunity();
    }

    public void Saveto(){
        opportunity opp= new opportunity();
        opp.Accountid= oppstring.Accountid;
        opp.name= oppstring.name;
        opp.closedate= oppstring.closedate;

        opp.StageName= oppstring.StageName;

        opp.leadSource= oppstring.LeadSource;

        opp.Ownerid= oppstring.Ownerid;

        opp.Amount= oppstring.Amount;

        opp.IsPrivate= oppstring.IsPrivate;

        opp.NextStep= oppstring.NextStep;

        opp.Type= oppstring.Type;

        opp.Probability= oppstring.Probability;

        opp.Campaignid= oppstring.Campaignid;


        insert opp;

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you new to Apex/Visualforce?  You're doing some things I've seen devs accustomed to building their own controllers do.  I recommend you check out Trailhead and also read up on StandardController (it will remove the necessity for most if not all of your code).

Comment: This will help you get on track:  https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_intro

Comment: Hey I am fairly new to apex coding. As you can see above code, I know how to write vf page and controller. I need hint data fro detail page to Visual force Edit page. Have yo ugot any example that I can refer to?

Comment: Please find this tutorial on how to replace standard VF page with custom VF page https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_tabs.htm

Answer (score 1):

you can use Pagereference class. something like

```
Pagerefernce pr = new Pagereference('/apex/yourPageName');
return pr;
```

Change your methods return type to **Pagereference** As you are using custom method this is a very easy approach to use.